# openstack : how to build a custom image from a VM

Tags: openstack, openstack-nova

I have a Virtual machine that I have customized with all the packages I need and it runs using virt-manager. I logged in and created a few directories and scripts in that image. I would like to "snapshot" it and run the snapshot on openstack. I don't care if the runtime state is preserved. All I want is for the packages and custom code that I have created on the virtual machine to be there.

I tried various things with the qcow2 image that virt-manager uses but that did not work. I don't quite understand - where are the changes I made to the file system?

I would like to generate an image with my customizations that I can subsequently run on an openstack cloud.

How can I proceed?

Thanks

Ranga

Comment: "I tried various things with the qcow2 image that virt-manager uses..." What did you try? What happened?

Comment: I don't see the the changes I made to the user file system that I made after I run diskimage-builder.